# div in middle of a HTML Table

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML Table with headings:

```
<table width="100%" align="center" rules="cols" frame="box" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
    <td width="" align="center"><strong><img src="/includes/images/padlock_closed.png" width="14px" /></strong></td>
    <td width="20px"><strong><input type="text" class="search" name="ticketnumber" placeholder="Ticket #" size="6" onkeyup="showUser(this.value)" /></strong></td>
    <td width="50px"><strong>Contact</strong></td>
    <td width="200px"><strong>Summary</strong></td>
    <td width="40px"><strong>Category</strong></td>
    <td width="30px"><strong>Open Date</strong></td>
    <td width="30px"><strong>Last Modified</strong></td>
    <td width="30px"><strong>Assigned To</strong></td>
</tr>
```

I am creating a live PHP/MySQL Search script and i need a div to show the results but i want to show them below these headings

I tried adding:

```
<div id="result">
'rest of HTML Table here...'
</div>

</table>
```

but it doesn't display the table correctly/in the correct format

how can i make it display correctly with a div in it?

Comment: What does 'doesn't display correctly' mean? Give us a jsfiddle!

Comment: You can't wrap part of table in div.

Comment: move <div> after </table>

Comment: i want the default content in the table to be inside the <div> then when the search takes places it replaces all the default content and replaces with the search results

Comment: I don't want to be the 'use CSS' pedant, but it's best practice to use CSS for the table styling, e.g. the `text-align: center` property instead of `align=center`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a `<div>`, you should have a header row that uses `<th>` tags (instead of using `<td>`'s as you currently have and then data rows that use `<td>` tags inside of a `<tr>` for each row.

Update: Example with `<tbody>`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 column 1 data</td>
            <td>Row 1 column 2 data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 column 1 data</td>
            <td>Row 2 column 2 data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can then write css for the `<tbody>` tag:

```
tbody { color: blue; }
```

Comment: do you have an example please

Comment: See here for the proper markup: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_headings

Comment: Looking at the w3schools example I just linked to, there's a duplicate `<tr>` before the first row of data (directly beneath the header row). You don't need the duplicate `<tr>`, otherwise its good.

Comment: so use <tr id="result"> rather than <div id="result"> ?

Comment: I would use a css `class` rather than `id` as you'll no doubt have multiple rows of data and therefore multiple `<tr>`'s. You could wrap all result data `<tr>`'s in a `<tbody>` tag as per the w3 definition to save on applying a css class to all rows of data: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TBODY

Comment: Where do i put the <tr> tag? do you have an example please?

Comment: Answer above updated with example as easier to format than in this comment!

Comment: so use <tbody class="result"> ?

Comment: Sure, or just reference the `<tbody>` tag directly as per my last update to my answer.